# PHP adding another item to a array

Tags: php, arrays, backend

I would like to add new elements to the array from the html form, but I don't understand how to add new element to the main array with this structure I tried array_push, but I failed

```
$menu = array(
               "1" => array (
                               "title" => 'Glowna',
                               "page"  => 'home', 
                               "url"   => "index.php",
                                ),
               "2" => array (
                               "title" => "Cennik",
                               "page"  => 'services',
                               "url"   => "index.php"            
                                       ),                                      
               "3" => array (
                               "title" => 'Portfolio',
                               "page"  => 'portfolio',
                               "url"   => "index.php"           
                                       ),
               "4" => array (
                               "title" => 'O nas',
                               "page"  => 'about',
                               "url"   => "index.php"               
                                       ),                      
               "5" => array (
                               "title" => 'Kontakt',
                               "page"  => 'contact',
                               "url"   => "index.php"             
                                       )
);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing array_push with your example and it worked perfectly fine, what's the problem?

Regarding what others said below, it seems php still recognizes string keys if they are numerical, because array push works perfectly fine even though the arrays keys are numerical strings. What they said **maybe** applies to keys that are true strings or not in numerical order.

```
$menu = array(
        "1" => array (
                        "title" => 'Glowna',
                        "page"  => 'home', 
                        "url"   => "index.php",
                         ),
        "2" => array (
                        "title" => "Cennik",
                        "page"  => 'services',
                        "url"   => "index.php"            
                                ),                                      
        "3" => array (
                        "title" => 'Portfolio',
                        "page"  => 'portfolio',
                        "url"   => "index.php"           
                                ),
        "4" => array (
                        "title" => 'O nas',
                        "page"  => 'about',
                        "url"   => "index.php"               
                                ),                      
        "5" => array (
                        "title" => 'Kontakt',
                        "page"  => 'contact',
                        "url"   => "index.php"             
                                )
);

array_push($menu, array("title" => 'number 6', "page"  => 'something', "url"   => "works.php"));

var_export($menu);
```

Results:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Glowna',
    'page' => 'home',
    'url' => 'index.php',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Cennik',
    'page' => 'services',
    'url' => 'index.php',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Portfolio',
    'page' => 'portfolio',
    'url' => 'index.php',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'O nas',
    'page' => 'about',
    'url' => 'index.php',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Kontakt',
    'page' => 'contact',
    'url' => 'index.php',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'number 6',
    'page' => 'something',
    'url' => 'works.php',
  ),
)
```

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/76d5dab43255459455f2e80e37ab281486009fc4

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a key, which would most likely be `"6"`, then supply an array as the value. Your code might look something like this:

```
$menu['6'] = array( 'title' => "Archives",
                    'page'  => "archives",
                    'url'   => "archives.php");
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: you need to update "archives' as "archives"

Comment: Good catch. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$menu` array is called an associative array as it has string values for keys.

For associative arrays you can't use `array_push`.

What you can do is

```
$menu["key"] = array("title" => 'Kontakt',"page" => 'contact',"url" => "index.php")
```

But looking at your array, you can have numeric indexes instead of string. If you use the following structure, you can make use of `array_push`

```
$menu = array(array ("title" => 'Glowna',
                     "page"  => 'home', 
                     "url"   => "index.php"),
              array ( "title" => "Cennik",
                      "page"  => 'services',
                      "url"   => "index.php"))
```

Notice the removal of "string keys" (ex: `"1" => array()`),

Now you can use array_push;

```
array_push($menu, array("title" => "Cennik", "page"  => 'services', "url"   => "index.php"))
```